# Controlling Bar Position in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating side by side bar charts that are slightly offset and I'd like to be able to control which bar is at the front and which one is behind. I've tried changing the order of the factors, however it always puts the same factor at the front. I'd like to place the school variable at the front and have the board data behind, just as a reference point. When I run the code R always places the school data behind.

```
library (ggplot2
library(reshape)

school <- c(92, 90, 88)
board <- c(87, 88, 88)
grade <- c("Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3")
df <- melt (data.frame (school, board, grade))
ggplot (df, aes(x=grade, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar (stat="identity", position =position_dodge(width=.5))
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Greg yup, i dont get it. But an (ugly) workaround - redefine the levels and order the data. ie `df$variable <- factor(df$variable , levels=c("board", "school")); df <- df[order(df$variable), ]`

Comment: When I reverse the factor levels, the `board` bars are red and are plotted behind the `school` bars, which are blue.

Comment: @joran; I share the OP's problem; reversing factor levels changes the colour of the bars but `school` remains behind. Hence ugly workaround

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked perfectly. You may want to add it as an answer.

Comment: @Greg; Glad it works, but its not really an answer as something a bit strange is going on that i dont understand - changing the levels should change the bars. What R version are you using. (im on Rv3.1 32bit on ubuntu)

Comment: @user20650 Well, only your first line (which switches the order of the levels) is actually necessary. So....re-ordering the levels _did_ work for you.

Comment: @joran; agreed it changes the levels but even after doing this the `school` bar remains behind.

Comment: @user20650 Oh, I see. Should have paid closer attention to the actual values rather than trusting the colors.

Comment: @user20650 I'm on v3.0.2, 64bit.

Comment: @Greg; thanks - so were on different builds but same result. [**not advised** but changing `stat="identity"` to `stat="bin"` removes the need for reordering `df`, after releveling `variable`]

Comment: My guess is that `stat_identity` is being a bit too aggressive. Re-ordering the values in the data frame appears to be sufficient for me; no need to relevel at all.

Comment: @joran; yes ordering `df` is enough. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you changed the levels of the factor and it didn't work. But, when I changed the levels it did work. Try relevel()

```
library (ggplot2)
library(reshape)

school <- c(92, 90, 88)
board <- c(87, 88, 88)
grade <- c("Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3")
df <- melt (data.frame (school, board, grade))
df

#releveling factor
levels(df$variable)
df$variable <- relevel(df$variable, ref="board")

ggplot (df, aes(x=grade, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar (stat="identity", position =position_dodge(width=.5))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same result. The workaround provided by user20650 seems to have done the trick.